# Calculated field in a Pivot Table to work out a % of two Count columns

Tags: pivot-table

I've tried everything to do what I feel should be really easy.

I have a column for names in my enquiries table. This Counts the number of enquiries. I have a second column for the status column (anything in the status column counts as booked, whether that's Paid, Booked or Cancelled, if it's not booked, it's blank, so a simple count here is fine).

I just want to make a calculated column that tells me how many bookings I've made against the enquiries. ie If I've had 20 enquiries and made 10 bookings, the result should be 50%.

I've tried =counta(names)/counta(status). But that just results in 1. I tried to test it with just =counta(names) and that resulted in 1s as well.

So now I'm stuck! Thanks for any help.